# Port 443 unresponsive, certificate installed correctly though (I think)

Tags: ssl, ubuntu, https, apache-2.2

System specs:

Ubuntu 10.04
Apache 2

Installed an SSL cert from GoDaddy, checked that it works by issuing the following on the server itself:

openssl s_client -showcerts -connect localhost:443

However when I issue that same command on my laptop and replace localhost with the domain of the actual server, the request just hangs and then times out.

I've run netstat -an on the server to make sure port 443 is open & listening and it is (for tcp connections).

I'm not sure what else to check.

Comment: Is Apache configured to listen on port 443?

Comment: This should probably get moved to serverforge, but until then:
1) Does netstat -anp | grep httpd show apache listening on 443 (:::443) (and probably also listening on :::80
2) Can you, assuming it is also listening on port 80, connect to http://<server>

Comment: stackoverflow.com specs: programming questions, programming questions, programming questions. Your question: off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Configure apache to listen on the external IP address, not just on localhost.
`netstat -a -n` should show something like this:

```
tcp    0   0  192.168.1.2:443   0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN    -
```

where the IP address (local address) is *not* 127.0.0.1. *0.0.0.0 is fine*.